# Install MySQL-python in virtualenv on Windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pip, mysql-python

I'm trying to install MySQL-python in my virtualenv (Windows 7 32b + Python 2.7.3), but unfortunately after command:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

I get error message:

```
Install packages failed: Error occurred when installing package MySQL-python. 

The following command was executed:

packaging_tool.py install --build-dir C:\Users\Grzegorz\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging3577041299153334552.tmp MySQL-python

The error output of the command:


Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
  Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Grzegorz\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging3577041299153334552.tmp\MySQL-python\setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "setup_windows.py", line 7, in get_config
    serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_key'])
WindowsError: [Error 2] Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

File "C:\Users\Grzegorz\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging3577041299153334552.tmp\MySQL-python\setup.py", line 15, in <module>

metadata, options = get_config()

File "setup_windows.py", line 7, in get_config

serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_key'])

WindowsError: [Error 2] Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Grzegorz\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging3577041299153334552.tmp\MySQL-python
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Grzegorz\pip\pip.log
```

If I try to install this package from binary MySQL-python-1.2.3.win32-py2.7.exe then everything install properly, but it's not solution for me.
Do you have any suggestions how can I properly install this package on Windows 7 (all other packages I'm able to install without any problems)?

Answer (score 22):

Did you try using :

```
 easy_install MySQL-python
```

It works for me in Windows 7 a long with Virtualenv. I had the same problem with pip.

Comment: Works like a charm! The `pip install MySQL-python` command tries to compile the library from source (which will fail if Visual Studio is not installed), while `easy_install MySQL-python` downloads the pre-compiled binary file.

Answer (score 11):

If you can install mysql-python globally (in C:/python27) from  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

then you can copy paste the following files from "C:/python/lib/site-packages" to your virtual environment "/lib/site-packages"

1. MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7.egg-info(folder)
2. MySQLdb(folder)
3. _mysql_exceptions.py/.pyc/.pyo
4. _mysql.pyd

**Don't need to copy mysql files from "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends" or "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends".

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Windows MSI installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/mysql-python/1.2.3/MySQL-python-1.2.3.win32-py2.7.msi/download) now on SourceForge. Try that, but if you'd rather build your own, for now (until 1.2.4 is released), you should be able to do this:

```
pip install http://svn.code.sf.net/p/mysql-python/svn/branches/MySQLdb-1.2/MySQLdb
```

The above assumes you have Subversion installed.